# Can I use OpenLDAP to authenticate users in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, authentication

I like to use OpenLDAP to authenticate my Oracle users. It should be possible to fetch at least the password from the directory.

There appearently is something for the Oracle LDAP servers, but would it work with OpenLDAP (plain, from i.e. Debian)?

Comment: Good idea. Let me change it back for a couple of hours.

Comment: Did you get this up and working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes!**

According to [this post](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201006/msg00371.html), you absolutely can, with significant speed improvements over OID.

Looking at this *absolutely ancient* [post](http://www.orafaq.com/maillist/oracle-l/2003/12/09/0633.htm), it was apparently possible back in 2003.

[Here's](http://web.archive.org/web/20070328211733/http://home.nc.rr.com/jtlayton/oid2openldap.html) the Archive.Org transcript of the page they reference.

This is a [Oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E14571_01/oid.1111/e10029/plugin_cust_ext_auth.htm#g124820) link about hooking OID up to an "external directory". Good luck.

Comment: Has anyone gotten Oracle user authentication with OpenLDAP working?  any technical details published anywhere?  I read the links above, but while some of them do claim success, there don't seem to be any technical details.  Also, I've been Google searching, to no avail.

Answer (score -2):

There's a [page](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Oracle/DBA_tips/LDAP/LDAP_8.shtml) describing step by step how to set up OpenLDAP to resolve TNS aliases.

Comment: Please don't create link-only answers.

Comment: Well, the procedure's quite lengthy, so reposting it here was not really possible. Plus, it's actually a better answer to the question than anything I've read here.

Comment: @FredPetillot and when that page moves somewhere else or just stops being there, your answer will contain zero bits of information.